# Property Set Overload Array vs. Non-Array

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, set, overloading

I'm trying to create a property that will allow the setting of a last name based on a variety of inputs. The code that calls this is parsing a name field. In some instances it will have a single last name, in others, a array of last names that need to be concatenated. I want to keep my concatenation code in a single place to make maintenance easier.

Here is my code, which of course doesn't work:

```
        Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return _LastName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _LastName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property LastName() As String()
        Set(ByVal value As String())
            For Each word As String In value
                _LastName &= word & " "
            Next

            _LastName = _LastName.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
```

I've tried numerous variations on this, even putting multiple Set in the same Property, but nothing seems to work. There must be some way to take in an array and a single instance value. The compiler clearly knows if the incoming object is an array or not.

I tried working with just a property of type String(), but then I can't return a String. The only solution that I can think of is differently named properties, which makes using the class more difficult, or a whole bunch of Subs and Functions overloading each other.

Suggestions?

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload properties, so the property can by either a `string` or a `string()`, not both.

Consider having a different name for the `string()` property:

```
Public WriteOnly Property LastNameArray() As String()
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        For Each word As String In value
            _LastName &= word & " "
        Next

        _LastName = _LastName.Trim
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to have a different name for the property for each of use reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If your output is going to be of a different type than your input, then you cannot use a property for it. There is nothing wrong with using a function for it, good practice would say that you have the function name (`LastName`), and prepend a verb on to it (`Get`), so you end up with a function anme like `GetLastName`.

```
Public  Function GetLastName(ByVal names As String()) As String
```

(excuse my very rusty VB if there is something blatantly wrong)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
        Public Property LastName() As Object
        Get
            Return _LastName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            If TypeOf (value) Is Array Then
                For Each word As String In value
                    _LastName &= word & " "
                Next

                _LastName = _LastName.Trim

            End If
            If TypeOf (value) Is String Then
                _LastName = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

Does anyone see a problem with this?